# pbs qsub - Output showing up in error file

Tags: linux, hpc, pbs, qsub

I have code that `ssh`s onto a cluster and does a job (in this case it performs `dd` to measure file copying speed)

```sh
...
job='some_job'
log='/home/logs' # where out and err is saved
cmd="dd if=/dev/zero of=${file} bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync"

ssh cluster "source .cshrc; echo $cmd | qsub -V -hard -l 'mem_free=2.0G,h_vmem=2.0G' -cwd -N $job -o $log'.log' -e $log'.err'"
```

The job works, however the output I want is somehow redirected to the `.err` file when I want it in the `.log` file.

some_job.log:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
```

some_job.err:

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 77.7467 s, 13.8 MB/s
```

Not sure what to change since I explicitly indicate in the script the file locations with the `-e` and `-o` options.

Comment: What shell is running on the far end?  Maybe you don't want to use a shell like TCSH that delivers that warning?

Answer (score 0):

So as trivial as it seems the message I'm looking for is indeed considered as `stderr`.  Due to the semantics of what I expected output to be, I thought this was incorrect.

Though this is the 'answer', I would appreciate any comments explaining these semantics (why the copying speeds are printed as `stderr`).

Comment: They go to stderr so they do not get mixed in with stdio if you were to pipe the output, for example: `ssh remote dd if=/dev/zero  bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync  > local1Gzeros`